# Gauss-Markov Theorem assumption of normality.

Tags: probability, statistics

Under the 6th assumption of Gauss-Markov Theorem, it states that if the conditional distribution of random errors is normal, then the conditional distribution of the least squares estimator will be normal aswell.

Why is this true?

Answer (score 0):

If the errors are conditionally normal, then the vector $y$ is conditionally joint normal. Now write
$$\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1} X'y.$$
Conditional on $X$, this is a linear function of $y,$ so it is also conditionally joint normal.